# access denied to directory/folder

Tags: windows-xp, cygwin

I just wasted an hour or so chasing this. I was able to resolve it but putting it in q/a form hoping others might benefit.

The symptom was that I could not access a directory. I could browse to it in explorer or command window. I could not even see its security permissions in properties window.

The folder is created by our build process, which meant I could pretty much do no work. Searching on net was no help.

Answer below.

Comment: "Denied"...also, it's not a great title.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it has to do with how `cygwin` does not lock a directory. The build process removed the directory (`rmdir /s u:\target`) and then recreated it (`mkdir u:\target`). I had a bash window where that directory was the current directory.

When the build process (bat file) called `rmdir` it *succeeded*, even `%errorlevel%` was 0. However the subsequent `mkdir` failed with `Access is denied.`. The build process unfortunately checked only for `rmdir` failure, not `mkdir`.

Thanks to `handle.exe` I found the folder to be in use by `bash.exe`, From there it was straightforward. Changing the current directory finally deleted the folder and another go at build set everything right.

I realize this is unix behavior to remove a file only after all handled to it are closed, but its simulation in windows is somewhat non-intuitive.